# Is there a way to improve MongoDB's Full-Text Search performance?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search

I am using MongoDB Atlas to serve my ~110k athlete data.

Each document contains a `name` field and a `name_foreign` field that has the name in a different language that is not supported by MongoDB's Full-Text Search.
In my Python app, I use Pymongo to return the results of the search based on the players' names in both English and the foreign language. I created an index so that I can score the search result based on the search query.

`db.players.create_index([ ("name", TEXT), ('name_foreign', TEXT) ])`

In my Python app, I detect the input string, and whenever it's in the other language, I tokenize the string and then input that into the `find` query (the `name_foreign` field in the database is already tokenized so that the Full-text search works).

## My GET players endpoint

```
try:
    # transform query if it's non-eng
    if detect(name) == '...': # some language
        query = ''
        for ch in name:
            if ch != ' ':
                query += ch + ' '
        query = query.rstrip()
    else:
        query = name
    players = list(db.players.find({ "$text": { "$search": query }},
                { 'score': { "$meta": "textScore" }}))
    players.sort(key = lambda k: (k['score'], k['reputation']), reverse = True)
    # Return results based on the input query
    return jsonify({ 'result': [player_to_dict(player) for player in players][:4]})

except: ...
```

I finally return the top-4 result of the search.
This works fine with English and the Full-Text search works great with it. However, when I use the other language, it works fine for short names, but when the name gets a little longer, it crashes giving me a memory leak error.

```
2019-11-28T21:51:47.301318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=799M(156.2%)
2019-11-28T21:51:47.301318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

This method worked well when the data was below 10k. Now that it has around 110k, it seems like I need a better way to do it.

I am new to this kind of stuff and I really want to hear some thoughts from experienced MongoDB users and eventually make it work better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do in the for loop, but I suggest that you look at the value of `query` before you pass it to mongo, just to make sure you are not putting spaces in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the memory you are using you could ask mongo to do the sorting for you, then get the first 4 results. This way, you will not be loading all the results to memory, sorting them and only using the top 4.

```py
from bson import SON
cur = collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match":{
            "$text": {
                "$search": "foo"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "textScore": {"$meta": "textScore"}
        }
    },
    { # best score and reputation at the top:
        "$sort": SON([("textScore", -1), ("reputation", -1)]) # must use SON and not a dict because the order of the sort matters here
    },
    {
        "$limit": 4
    }   
])

list(cur) # get top 4 results from the sort
```

Mongo has a special [optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-limit-memory-optimization) for a limit phase after a sort. You don't really need to sort 110k documents to pick 4 documents, so this will also be much faster than doing it on your side.